# Vue cli 3 - NYC Istanbul code reports not including vue files

Tags: vuejs2, istanbul, lcov, vue-cli-3, nyc

I have been trying for hours now to get the istanbul code coverage reports up and running for my new vue (typescript based) project, generated with the vue-cli v3.

Whenever I run my tests: (`nodemon --exec nyc vue-cli-service test:unit`) only the .ts files are included, even though I have specificly set that nyc should include those files:

#### Package.json

```
"nyc": {
    "check-coverage": true,
    "per-file": true,
    "lines": 80,
    "instrument": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "statements": 80,
    "functions": 80,
    "branches": 80,
    "include": [
        "apollo-server/**/*.{ts,vue}",
        "apollo-server/*.vue",
        "src/**/*.{ts,vue}",
        "src/*.vue"
    ],
    "exclude": [
    ],
    "reporter": [
        "lcov",
        "text",
        "text-summary"
    ],
    "extension": [
        ".ts",
        ".vue"
    ],
    "cache": true,
    "all": true
}
```

I have also tried setting `nyc.instrument` and `nyc.sourceMap` to false in order to allow a custom loader in the webpack configuration like so:

### Vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
baseUrl: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    ? '/'
    : '/',
configureWebpack: config => {
    // if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "coverage") {
        config = Object.assign(config, {
            module: Object.assign(config.module, {
                rules: config.module.rules.concat([
                    {
                        test: /\.(ts|tsx|vue)$/,
                        enforce: 'post',
                        include: [
                            path.resolve('src'),
                            path.resolve('apollo-server')
                        ],
                        loader: 'istanbul-instrumenter-loader'
                    }
                ])
            })
        })
    // }
}
```

I have also tried doing this using the `vue.config.js > chainWebpack` hook and when using a vue config instead of the package.json it results in no files being included at all:

### Vue.config.js with chainWebpack instead of configureWebpack

```
chainWebpack: config => {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "coverage") {
        config.module
            .rule("istanbul")
                .test(/\.(ts|tsx|vue)$/)
                .enforce("post")
                .pre()
                .include
                    .add(__dirname + "/apollo-server")
                    .add(__dirname + "/src")
                    .end()
                .use("istanbul-instrumenter-loader")
                    .loader("istanbul-instrumenter-loader")
                    .options({
                        esModules: true
                    })
                    .end()
    }
}
```

It might be due to the `__dirname + [filename]` I am using in this config, though I have no idea what else it should be. I was doing this based on this link: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/1363, where I was supposed to add `'src'`, though it results in an error stating that the included paths are not absolute.

Comment: Facing same issue. Exclude/Include not working.